# What is the solution for this sql complex interview question?

Tags: sql

I am pretty good at sql.
I have faced this question in interview and was unable to figure out the answer.

Question:
There is a **location** table 
With 3 columns (source, destination, distance)as show below

Location:

```
Source - Destination - Distance
Hyderabad - Chennai - 700
Chennai - Hyderabad - 700
Hyderabad - Bangalore -650
```

As given above , Hyderabad to Chennai or Chennai to Hyderabad both mean the same as the distance will always be same.

So we need to write the query to so that the output should not have such kind of duplicate records.

In the above case output should be

Location:

```
Source - Destination - Distance
Hyderabad - Chennai - 700
Hyderabad - Bangalore -650
```

Comment: Definitely more complex than it first appears! +1

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want under these conditions:

```
select l.*
from location l
where l.source < l.destination;
```

Comment: As pcdev points out in his answer: "my only criticism is that this only works reliably if records for both directions are in the table for any two locations".  Just leaving this friendly comment so you get a notification. :)

Answer (score 1):

Gordon Linoff has a good succinct answer, however my only criticism is that this only works reliably if records for both directions are in the table for any two locations. If this was a collection of legs you had travelled in the past and had only travelled from Hyderabad > Bangalore but never taken the return trip (as per the supplied data), you wouldn't get a result for that pair. In OP's question it's not clear if this is a consideration.

Another consideration not mentioned in the question or in any answers so far is what happens if you have two legs of a round trip that have (for whatever reason) a different value.  This is conceivable and with other answers will result in duplicates.

This should work more reliably (thanks for the comment on `group by` @DavidדודוMarkovitz):

```
select case when l.source < l.destination then l.source else l.destination end as source,
      case when l.source > l.destination then l.source else l.destination end as destination,
      max(l.distance) distance
from location l
group by
      case when l.source < l.destination then l.source else l.destination end,
      case when l.source > l.destination then l.source else l.destination end
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/66d59d/3/0)

Comment: You got the essence of the question but your syntax is problematic. If you  use GROUP BY it should be on the CASE expressions, ***not*** on the original columns. However, a simple distinct will do.

Comment: The GROUP BY does not function as you would expect, `Hyderabad - Chennai` and `Chennai - Hyderabad` would not be in the same group. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d4796/3

Comment: Thanks @DavidדודוMarkovitz, you're right - thanks!  Fixing and adding some explanation now...

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz to address your comment "a simple distinct will do", I was trying to resolve the issue of differing to/from distances with aggregation.  The `group by` was not for duplicate elimination. See edited answer above which I believe would work best under most likely input data.

Comment: Now that you have the GROUP BY right, there is no use for the DISTINCT

Comment: As for the interpretation of the question - "as the distance will always be same.". If the distance could be different between the same two locations, the interviewers would have asked explicitly for min/max of the distance or something in that direction and not for duplications removal.

Comment: _If the distance could be different between the same two locations, the interviewers would have asked explicitly for min/max of the distance or something in that direction and not for duplications removal_  I've learned to never trust input data ;)  If duplicate removal is the goal, then aggregation is essential imo.

Comment: I have learnt the same :-). However, aggregation would not fix the data. Choosing min/max/avg is not a technical decision, it is a business decision and therefore should be dictated by the business (or the interviewers in that case)

Answer (score 1):

If your SQL DB/engine supports LEAST/GREATEST (it is an ISO syntax, so many of them do):

```
select  distinct
        least   (source, destination) as source
       ,greatest(source, destination) as destination
       ,distance

from    location
```

[SQL Fiddle - Postgres](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d4796/1/0)
[SQL Fiddle - MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d47969/1/0)
[SQL Fiddle - Oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/25a193/1/0)

If not:

```
select  distinct
        case when source < destination then source else destination end as source
       ,case when source < destination then destination else source end as destination
       ,distance

from    location
```

[SQL Fiddle - SQLite](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d4796/2/0)
[SQL Fiddle - SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d4796/1/0)

Answer (score 1):

This is a good discussion and the solution by @pcdev is good. The improvement i can make over this is to keep the original source and destination intact for those cases where there isnt a return journey.

In the example by pcdev if you got record like this

```
C --> B
A --> D
D --> A
```

the output would be

```
B --> C (The original order is not preserved) 
A --> D 

create table location ( Source nvarchar(max), Destination nvarchar(max), Distance int)

insert into location values
('Hyderabad', 'Chennai',   700),
('Chennai',   'Hyderabad', 700),
('Hyderabad', 'Bangalore', 650),
('Cochin', 'Bangalore', 650),
('Hyderabad', 'England', 650),
('England', 'Hyderabad', 650)

select * from (
select l.source
       ,l.destination
       ,case when l.source < l.destination then l.source else l.destination end as source_col
       ,case when l.source > l.destination then l.source else l.destination end as destination_col
       ,row_number() over(partition by case when l.source < l.destination then l.source else l.destination end
                                       ,case when l.source > l.destination then l.source else l.destination end
                           order by l.source) as rnk
from location l
)x
where x.rnk=1

+-----------+-------------+------------+-----------------+-----+
|  source   | destination | source_col | destination_col | rnk |
+-----------+-------------+------------+-----------------+-----+
| Cochin    | Bangalore   | Bangalore  | Cochin          |   1 |
| Hyderabad | Bangalore   | Bangalore  | Hyderabad       |   1 |
| Chennai   | Hyderabad   | Chennai    | Hyderabad       |   1 |
| England   | Hyderabad   | England    | Hyderabad       |   1 |
+-----------+-------------+------------+-----------------+-----+
```

DB FIDDLE LINK
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=4f301944741a6c024073fb7cb01691fc